# Status not updating

Tags: php, html

I'm currently doing this change status feature, and i plan to change the status by just clicking the change button, a prompt message will appear and the status will be changed. However, when i press the ok from the prompt, nothing happens and no data was updated and it just returned the page i was at. Was there anything that i missed out?

PHP code:

```
    <?php
        if(isset($_GET['idd'])){
            $idd = $_GET['idd'];   
            $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM orders WHERE order_id='$idd' limit 0,1");
            $row = $query->fetch_assoc();

            $id = $row['order_id'];
            $status = 'Warehouse A';
            $session = $_SESSION['username'];
            $result = $conn->query("UPDATE orders(status,editor) SET status='".$status."',editor='".$session."' WHERE order_id='".$id."'");

            if($result){//success update message
        ?>
                <script>
                    window.location.href='orders_mid.php';
                </script>
                <?php
            }
        }
    ?>
```

html button code:

```
<td>
    <a onclick="return confirm('Are You Sure The Goods Are Delivered to Warehouse A?')" 
       href="?idd=<?= $rows['order_id']; ?>"
       id="changeBtn"
       class="btn btn-danger"> Change </a>
</td>
```

Comment: Your UPDATE syntax `UPDATE orders(status,editor) SET status...` AFAIK should be `UPDATE orders SET status...`

Comment: @NigelRen thanks for the feedback. So the update query was written wrongly, thanks again for the advice!

Comment: as a note, you're open to SQL injection and should address ^^